# words of $~4~$ diff letters formed out of $~7~$ capital letters, $~3~$ vowels, and $~5~$ consonants. (description in body)

Tags: combinatorics

If each word starts with capital letter and contains at least $~1~$ vowel

Rather than being a question, its a doubt. I know its correct solution but don't know what's wrong with proceeding this way.
$$^7C_1 × ^3C_1 × ^7C_2$$

Comment: Are there vowels in capital letters?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  I assume you meant to say words of four different letters formed out of $7$ capital letters, $3$ lower case vowels, and $5$ lower case consonants.  That should be specified in the question, which should be stated explicitly in the body of the question even if it is written in the title.  Also, you should state the correct solution so that readers have a basis for comparison with your proposed solution.  If my interpretation of your question is correct, the short answer to your question is that your proposed solution counts each word with more than one vowel multiple times.